# How is the prosthetic eye not pulverised by such power?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War*:

> Rocket gives Thor a [prosthetic eye](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Thor%27s_Prosthetic_Eye) that he got from the previous *Guardian of the Galaxy* films.

And it does not seem to be a special/magic/enchanted/powerful item.

Then, in the middle of the movie:

> when Thor needs to reactivate the forge of Nidavellir, he takes the power of a star!

**So, how/why does this object not get destroyed in the process?**

Comment: Do we know that this isn't a special eye made of some super powered metal?

Comment: IIRC, isn't he facing *away* from the thing in your spoiler?

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm not sure, hence my question.

Comment: @F1Krazy that's what I remember too, but considering the huge heat of the "thing", a "normal" object would probably melt anyway

Comment: The same reason his clothes aren't pulverised, or burned, or ripped or even smudged: **plot armour**

Comment: @Möoz I don't remember from where does his armor come from, but I'm less bothered by that because of "Asgardian steel" or whatever they used to create his armor. Because here, we can assume (not at 100% but still) that Thor, as a God himself, wear special clothes/armor that reflect his power. But yeah, you got a point here.

Comment: Thor’s legendary God-like eyelid protected it.

Comment: And his eyelashes are divinely fabulous darling!

Comment: You mean pirate angel eyelid.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite If I had evidence to confirm my recollection that he closed his eyes, I'd steal that comment as an answer. What more can we provide, besides plot armor?

Comment: @Saiboogu We’ve got that, and the fact that he’s sensibly got his back to the star. And hey, for all we know, the eye is super-durable and made of the exact same stuff the forge is made of.

Answer (score 1):

His back was facing the star, which clearly made a huge difference to how hot his front got, because Rocket was able to touch him immediately afterwards.

Comment: I like this answer. Why not. If his back wasn't burned his body could certainly act as a heat shield for the front.

Comment: If Rocket was effectively able to touch him afterwards, that is actually a good answer to my question.

Comment: He also had his eyes closed for most of the process. He does look over his shoulder into the star at one point (do not try this at home), but he does it with his left, i.e. birth, eye.